# outputting a bunch of json returned values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

```
$('.more').live("click",function() {
    var id = $('.wallPosts:last').attr("relOne");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/regUserDash/ajaxMore",
        data:  {id: id},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
                $("#morebox").append(data.idWallPosts);
        }
    });
});
```

Using the code above how would I output a bunch of json returned values? Below are my json values:

```
{"idwallPosts":"803"}{"idwallPosts":"798"}{"idwallPosts":"797"}{"idwallPosts":"796"}{"idwallPosts":"793"}{"idwallPosts":"792"}{"idwallPosts":"789"}{"idwallPosts":"785"}{"idwallPosts":"780"}
```

Below is my codeigniter code:

```
public function ajaxMore() {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM wallposts WHERE idwallPosts < '$id' ORDER BY idwallPosts DESC LIMIT 9");
        foreach($result->result() as $row) {
            echo json_encode(array('idwallPosts' => $row->idwallPosts));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your JSON values should be listed as properties wrapped in a single object .. `{"key1":"val","key2":"val2", ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `ajaxMore()` function to something like:

```
public function ajaxMore() {
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM wallposts WHERE idwallPosts < '$id' ORDER BY idwallPosts DESC LIMIT 9");

    $idwallPosts = array();
    foreach($result->result() as $row)
    {
        $idwallPosts[] = $row->idwallPosts));
    }

    print json_encode(array('posts'=>$idwallPosts));
    exit;
}
```

In the ajax call, add `dataType:'json'` to the options of $.ajax, and use the parameter data in the success function as:

```
success: function(data) {
    var div_to_append = "<div>";

    $.each(data.posts, function(i,post){
        div_to_append += "<p>" + post + "</p>";
    });

    $(div_to_append).appendTo("#morebox");        
}
```

Comment: I've done this but idWallPosts isn't being recognized. http://pastebin.com/t8BF6eDk - when I run code1 I get undefined. but when I replace this.idWallPosts with data.idWallPosts I get the following alert: [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], . Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Michael-Grigsby I've changed my answer. Have you tried it? It should work

Answer (score 2):

Add `dataType:'json'` to the options of `$.ajax`, and use the parameter `data` in the success function as any other array object to iterate it

```
$.each(data, function( .. ) { .. } ):
```